# search bar for json array ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using ionic 3 to build a market app and one of my list items is the "products"

my "products page" get items from JSON array by HTTP post request, not entry data

```
postProducts(type){
return this.http.get('URL').map(res => res.json()); 
}
```

I want to build a search bar to filter my products by name

any help?

Comment: can you show me data structure in your json. show i will add method which filter your list.

Comment: What is this? How you will get list of products using http post method

Comment: 0: {id: 40, name: "كنور خلطة الكبسه",                                                                    
   desc: "2 قطعه",                                                                                                  price: "2750",                                                                                                   type: "العروض الخــاصه", …}

Comment: do you want to filter arabic words right?

Comment: yes, some errors appeared lets look how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

```js
allrecs = []; 
postProducts.subscript((response)=>{
this.allrecs.push(response); 
}, (error)=>{
  console.log("error")
})

filterRecs(searchTerm){
  return this.allrecs.filter((rec) => {
    return rec.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });    
}
```

Hope your record like : 
{id: 40, name: "كنور خلطة الكبسه", desc: "2 قطعه", price: "2750", type: "العروض الخــاصه"}, 
{id: 40, name: "كنور خلطة الكبسه", desc: "2 قطعه", price: "2750", type: "العروض الخــاصه"}
so on..

Comment: This method i m using everywhere in my application. but in my case i have records in english.

Comment: no, no errors in console log but when I want to search nothing happens

Comment: debug filterRecs method

Comment: i solve it with this function                                                          
          onInput($event){
          this.items=[];
          for(let i =0 ; i < this.items2.length ; i++){
       
    
    
    if(this.items2[i].name.toLowerCase().includes(this.myInput.toLowerCase())){
          this.items.push(this.items2[i]);
      }
      else{  

       }
    }